# formatting certain texts in \fancyvrb environments automatically

Tags: fancyvrb

I have for example the following `Verbatim` environment from the `fancyvrb` package:

```
\begin{Verbatim}
>>> 1+1
2
>>>
\end{Verbatim}
```

Whenever ">>>" appears, I want to color it blue. Instead of manually coloring those, can I do the coloring job automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right tool for your use case is the [listings](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) package: In addition to coloring the prompts, it will do a whole bunch of other things appropriate to code as well. It doesn't color python prompts by default, but it's easy to customize.

It can be as simple as this:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{
  otherkeywords={>>>},     % used only because >>> is not an identifier
  morekeywords=[3]{>>>},
  keywordstyle={[3]\color{blue}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
>>> 1+1
2
>>>  
\end{lstlisting}
```

But you'll probably want a few more adjustments to make it more python-like. 
If you like syntax coloring, add `style={python-idle-code}` to `\lstset{}` to get an IDLE-like color scheme. (It's defined in `listings-python.prf`, which must be included separately. Clunky...) Or you could use `language={python}`, for a black and white basic scheme. Either way, I would also recommend `showstringspaces=false` and `tabsize=4`. So here's a complete almost-MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Optional:
\input{listings-python.prf}
\lstset{
  style={python-idle-code},
  showstringspaces=false,  % true by default for python
  % tabsize=4,
}

% Blue prompts 
\lstset{
  otherkeywords={>>>},    % used only because >>> is not an identifier
  morekeywords=[3]{>>>},
  keywordstyle={[3]\color{blue}},
}


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
>>> 1+1
2
>>> def hello():
    print("Hello, world!")
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: colored python]

Comment: Beautiful. Super easy to implement, too. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Here an approach, just insert your verbatim text inside `VerbatimOut` environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}

\begin{VerbatimOut}{file.txt}
>>> 1+1
2
>>>
\end{VerbatimOut}

{
\def\greater{\char62}
\catcode`>=\active
\VerbatimInput[defineactive={\def>{\textcolor{blue}{\greater}}}]{file.txt}
}


\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: This also colours single `>` signs, which does not seem to be what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Replace `\def>` with `\def>>>`.

Comment: and if the code contains `>>>>` ?

Comment: Also `\def>>>` does not work, single `>` results in ` Use of > doesn't match its definition`.